# Creating my own action for BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an method like this:

```
public static boolean checkConnection(){

    if(getConnection()!=null){
        return true;
    }else

        return false;
}
```

I trying to listen to the result of this method throughout my application. Till my application is alive. Only inside my application

How should I create my own action so that in `BroadcastReceiver` I can listen to this method and show an dialog when it returns false and hide the dialog automatically when it start returning true?

How and what will be the best approach to do this?

```
public class BroadCastActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

ConnectionReceverLocal mReceverLocal;
Button mSwithcOn,mSwitchOff;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_broad_cast);

    /*Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.broadcast.myconnectionbroadcast");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);*/
    mReceverLocal = new ConnectionReceverLocal();
    mSwitchOff = (Button)findViewById(R.id.switchoff);
    mSwithcOn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.switchon);
    mSwitchOff.setOnClickListener(this);
    mSwithcOn.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void sendMessage() {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("Connection result Checking Asynctasks", ""+ConnectionProvider.checkConnection());
            return ConnectionProvider.checkConnection();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.broadcast.myconnectionbroadcast");
            // Add data
            intent.putExtra("message", result);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(BroadCastActivity.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }




    }.execute();
} 


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceverLocal);
}




@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceverLocal,
            new IntentFilter("com.alignminds.broadcast.myconnectionbroadcast"));
    sendMessage();
}




public class ConnectionReceverLocal extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public ConnectionReceverLocal() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AlertDialog.Builder mDBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BroadCastActivity.this);

        Boolean intentAction = intent.getBooleanExtra("message", false);
        if(intentAction==false)
        {
            Log.d("Connection is false in broadcast recever", "Connection is false");
            if(mDBuilder!=null)
            {
                mDBuilder.setMessage("No Network");
                mDBuilder.create().show();  
            }

        }else {
            Log.d("Connection is true in broadcast recever", "Connection is true");
            if(mDBuilder!=null)
            {
                mDBuilder.setMessage("Network Ok");
                mDBuilder.create().show();  
            }
        }

    }
}




@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v==mSwithcOn)
    {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
    if(v==mSwitchOff)
    {

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Send a broadcast with whatever action you want like this

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(); 
   intent.setAction("my_fancy_action");
   intent.putExtra(EVENT_MESSAGE, message);
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
   ```
2. Subclass BroadcastReceiver class to listen for broadcasts

   ```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     String intentAction = intent.getAction();
     // Do something
   }
   ```
3. Register your receiver to listen to the broadcast

   ```
   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
   filter.addAction("my_fancy_action");
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
   ```

Comment: Thanks yaar after seeing your answer, i really got the idea and i did in the following way  can you check you mean this only ? I have edited my question. But it will not work in every activity , i have to write separate for other activities

Comment: Can you check my question once again , does it is same as your anwer

Comment: An easy solution would be to create a base class that extends Activity which will contain this logic. All other activities should extend this base class so that they get this logic for free. When you do that, each activity will receive the broadcast.

Comment: Yes that is , i got it . But i have a situation here .The recever is calling itself only once  the activity starts , not each time the method returns value changes  why ?

Comment: You are calling sendMessage(); in onResume(), which sends the broadcast once. If you call that method in other places, your receiver will receive the broadcasts.

Comment: should i call this method in service so that it is keep on running till the application is alive

Comment: Call it in onCreate or onResume of your base activity so that it is called whenever an activity is created or resumed. Alternately, you can call it in a service at regular intervals, if that's what you need to do.